# Undefined prop value in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to read an array item in a child component via props. Logging the array in the child component works. But if I try to access a property of one of the array items by indexing it with the :id from match.params, it tells me that I can't access a property of 'undefined'.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

tours.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// Page Imports
import Summary from "../pages/summary";
import Details from "../pages/details";

// Component Imports
import Homebutton from "../components/homebutton";

class Tours extends Component {
  state = {
    tours: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    fetch("/tours")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ tours: res }));
  }

  render() {
    const tours = this.state.tours;

    return (
      <section className="tours-page">
        <div className="center-box">
          <h2>Tours</h2>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path={this.props.match.url}
            render={props => <Summary {...props} tours={tours} />}
          />
          <Route
            path={this.props.match.url + "/:id"}
            render={props => <Details {...props} tours={tours} />}
          />
        </Switch>
        <Homebutton />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Tours;
```

details.js

```
import React from "react";

const Details = ({
  tours,
  match: {
    params: { id }
  }
}) => (
  <section className="details">
    <h2>{tours[id]["name"]}</h2>
  </section>
);

export default Details;
```

Comment: does the problem occurs in the `Details` component ? is the `match` prop undefined ?

Comment: where is tours ? can you show us where it is populating ?

Comment: standard - `this.state.tours` unavailable on initial render (empty array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `componentDidMount`always gets called after first `render`, you must validate your props to avoid app crashes:

---

```
const Details = ({
  tours,
  match: {
    params: { id }
  }
}) => (
  <section className="details">
    <h2>{tours.length && tours[id]["name"]}</h2>
  </section>
);
```

Comment: I thought the problem came from retrieving the `match` param, but in fact the problem comes from the `tours` property, I think `{tours.length &&` will not fully solve the problem, it would be better having `{tours[id] && tours[id]["name"]`

Comment: No tours[id] will throw an error because it is still undefined on first render.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, but `tours` is an object. `.length` does not work here as intended I suppose.

Comment: Nope tours is an array, initialized in state.

Comment: My bad, it really is :)

Comment: tours will not be undefined on first render because the initial state gives it the value of an empty array `state = {
    tours: []
  };`

Comment: Yes, it will be an empty array on first render but when access an element from an empty array it throws error because there'll be no element

Comment: your assumption is wrong, `const arr = [];` then `console.log(arr[10])` will not thow an error, it will just return `undefined`, you should read the javascript documentation

Comment: Yes but if we access property out of it it will throw an error. So it is recommended not to validate empty array and it is preferable to check array length , otherwise why should we check empty array's element. This is more about code readability

Comment: do you think it will work using your code if `tours.length = 1` and `id = 3` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I believe this is about our logic implementation why would we let inaccessible elements to be part of our validation. Your argument is great at great extent. But we write code more confidently that shouldn't pass such values,

Comment: Very valid point @OlivierBoissé. Also just checking the length like that `tours.length` might render a `0` to the DOM. Safer one is: `!!tours.lenght`. But, I totally agree with @OlivierBoissé here. We should think of every circumstance.

Comment: because the user can easily change the `url`, as the `id` comes from the `url` you should definitely check that the parameter is valid, @devserkan totally agree for the `!!tours.length` or `tours.length > 0` as in my opinion checking the length is not sufficient in this case

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that `tours[id]` is not `undefined` you should check it first

```
<section className="details">
 <h2>{tours[id] && tours[id]["name"]}</h2>
</section>
```